# How to block docker image version of services in Github action in renovate config

Tags: docker, github-actions, renovate

In my CI/CD workflow, i've added renovate but i'v some PR for version upgrade i don't want. For example, it suggest me to upgrade mysql version in my yml file defining github action workflow. Here i use :

```
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
```

But it suggest me to make this upgrade

```
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
```

I don't want to do it for the moment (too much work to migrate it, will do when ready)

How to deactivate in renovate this kind of suggestion ? My workflows use many services, some needs to be updated, some i don't want. I wasn't able to find which rules i need to add to my renovate file to disable upgrades proposals for only some targeted services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution

```
{
  "matchDatasources": [
    "docker"
  ],
  "matchPackagePatterns": ["mysql"],
  "enabled": false
}
```